# My react frontend not establishing connection with my node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to get my react frontend to establish connection with my node backend. The node backend works when I am using PostMan. I have gone through most of the options suggested on this plateform but none is helping.

This is the Fetch request in react

```
import axios from 'axios'

// Sending Request to register User
let URL = "/user/"

const register = async (userData) => {

  let response = await axios.post(URL + 'register', userData)

  if (response.data) {
     localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))
  }

  return register.data
}
```

This is my package.json file for the react:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "options": {
  "allowedHosts": [
    "localhost",
    ".localhost"
  ],
  "proxy":"http://localhost:8000"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
   "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
   "axios": "^1.1.2",
   "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
   "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
   "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
   "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
   "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
   "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ]
   }
 }
```

This is my Node index.js file to handle the post request

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { connectToDb } = require('./database/db');

const cors = require('cors')

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

connectToDb();

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(cors())
app.use('/user', require('./routes/userRoutes'))


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`)
})
```

What should am I not doing right?

Comment: You can try to change the URL. I mean instead of "/user/" you can try "/user".
Also, on this kind of problem it's little tough to identify the problem. So, better will be debug yourself by checking every line with console.log

Comment: I managed to solve it by removing the proxy from the package.json and writing the URL in the Fetch request in full. And it worked for me :)